# How do I permanently disable a specific sound card on Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My 16.04 system has three sound cards (builtin, USB, monitor):

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3266 Analog [ALC3266 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Audio [USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Audio [USB Audio], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: V2100 [Vengeance 2100], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I never use my internal sound card under any circumstances, and would like to permanently remove it so that sound can not be played through my PC speakers (this is specifically card 0 on device 0).

Is there a way to tell ALSA/Pulseaudio to completely ignore this card short of blacklisting the Intel sound module?

Comment: Wouldn't disabling it at BIOS/UEFI be a better solution than a software "hack"? Most motherboards have that option for many integrated devices (Ethernet, sound card and even integrated graphics when a discrte one is available).

Comment: @MichaelBay I haven't been able to find a BIOS option to disable the internal sound card yet, though I haven't looked too thoroughly.